# MySQL: Trying to get Current date with current hour, without minutes and seconds

Tags: mysql, date, time

I am trying this:

```
SELECT matchId FROM Matches where matchDate = CURRENT_DATE + HOUR(CURRENT_TIME) + ':00:00'
```

but cant get it to work. When I manually do this, it works:

```
SELECT matchId FROM Matches where matchDate = '2018-01-31 16:00:00'
```

I tried many variations of, containing CURDATE(), CURRENT_DATE, etc... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use **NOW()**

```
SELECT matchId FROM Matches where matchDate = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%y-%m-%d %h:00:00");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `DATE_FORMAT`, with `%Y-%m-%d` for date and `%H` for hours.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "Date : %Y-%m-%d Hour : %H")
```

It returns

```
Date : 2018-01-31 Hour : 15
```